# CSS selector for details element when opened

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector (like a pseudo class) that can target the `details` element when it is open?

One possible use for this would be to change the color of the `summary` element when the user open the `details` element.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the attribute `[open]` selector

```css
details summary {
  background: pink;
}

details {
  background: lightgreen;
}

details[open] summary {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Details</summary>
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, incidunt dolores! Laudantium fugit aspernatur rem autem, expedita ut id necessitatibus, perferendis, accusantium esse repudiandae?
</details>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you can also use `details:not([open])` to find closed `details` elements, though it's often better to have a general `details` rule and override parts of it in `details[open]`.